# Trying to program a Kinesis keyboard (kb133pc) and it is not working as expected

Tags: kinesis-advantage

I am trying to program the keyboard but I press <kbd>Program</kbd>+<kbd>f12</kbd>, the lights start to blink fast. I press the "origin", and the lights should keep blinking, but slower.

The problem is that they still blink fast and from this point there is nothing to do.
No matter how many keys I press, the lights keep blinking fast until you press <kbd>Program</kbd>+<kbd>f12</kbd> again.

Anyone has this problem before? I think this is a pre-2000 keyboard. I have checked that all the keys work.

Answer (score 1):

From the manual at https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1462317/Kinesis-Kb133pc.html?page=25#manual <kbd>Program</kbd> + <kbd>f12</kbd>:

> #### Remapping (moving) key actions (Progrm + F12)
>
> Briefly hold down the Progrm key and tap F12. The keyboard's lights will flash
> rapidly. To copy a key, first tap the "source" key whose action you want to copy
> somewhere else. The lights will flash more slowly. Now tap the key where you
> want the new action to appear. The lights will resume rapid flashing. You can
> repeat this sequence with a different pair of keys or exit with Progrm plus F12.

Presumably you need to have set up a macro on a key first in order to copy it to another key.